# How do you implement an array into an AWK expression?

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, awk, multiple-columns

I am writing a script, and I have delimited file that looks like this.

```
1|Anderson|399.00|123                                  
2|Smith|29.99|234                                  
3|Smith|98.00|345                                   
4|Smith|29.98|456                                   
5|Edwards|399.00|567  
6|Kreitzer|234.56|456
```

Here's an awk statement that will grab all the values in column one of a row that contain "Smith".

```
echo $(awk -F '|' 'BEGIN {count=0;} $2=="Smith" {count++; print $1}' customer)
```

The output would be:

```
2 3 4
```

How could I make it so I am also inputting the values into an array as awk increments. I tried this:

```
echo $(awk -F '|' 'BEGIN {count=0;} $2=="Smith" {count++; arr[count]=$1; print $1}' customer)
```

Edit: Later into the script, when I type

```
echo ${array[1]}
```

nothing outputs.

Comment: and??????????????????????????

Comment: You cannot transfer arrays from `awk` to the shell. `arr[count]` is in `awk`, `${array[1]}` is in shell. Perhaps you are looking for the `END` section?

Comment: Oh, well that makes sense.. How would you implement the END section in such a way that I can use the array throughout the rest of the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an easy solution. Set the output of awk into a variable. Then turn the variable into an array.

```
list=$(awk -F '|' 'BEGIN {count=0;} $2=="Smith" {count++; print $1}' customer)

array=($list)
```

Typing:

```
echo ${array[1]}
```

Will give you the second entry in the array

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be right! Perhaps, I might haven't got your question correctly?

I slightly enhanced your code to print the values stored in the array at the end of execution. Also, there is a `print` statement just before the values are printed.

```
echo $(awk -F '|' 'BEGIN {count=0;} $2=="Smith" {count++; arr[count]=$1; print $1} END { print "Printing the inputs"; for (i in arr) print  arr[i] }' customer)
2 3 4 Printing the inputs 2 3 4
```

Further, look at [this site](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/awk-arrays-explained-with-5-practical-examples/) for more examples.

Comment: Oh. Your's works. For some reason, when I type 

   echo ${array[1]}

on the next line down, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Looking for something like this?

```
awk -F "|" '$2=="Smith" {arr[count++]=$1}
            END {n=length(arr); for (i=0;i<n;i++) print (i+1), arr[i]}' in.file
```

#### OUTPUT

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Comment: I simply want to take the output, and put it into an array. So the array should look like arr[0]=2, arr[1]=3, arr[2]=4. However, later into my script, when I type "echo ${array[1]}" nothing is outputted.